# Background Image and Logo Image is not displayed in jsp page?

Tags: javascript, java, css, image, jsp

I am new to integrate UI Design in application. I have a jsp page and whick code is given below:

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page import="java.util.Enumeration"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<jsp:directive.include file="include_metatags.jsp" />
<title><s:message code="form.home.testEvosnapResponse" arguments="${applicationScope['APPLICATION_HEADER_TEXT']}"/></title>
<jsp:directive.include file="include_head.jsp" />

<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
        body,html{
                    background-image      : url("resources/img/xyymm/home.jpg");
                    background-attachment : fixed;
                    background-position   : center center;
                    background-size       : cover;  
                }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <jsp:include page="menu.jsp">
        <jsp:param value="xylyx" name="currentpage" />
    </jsp:include>

    <div class="container amo2">
        <div class="card card-container2"
            style="padding: 20px 40px 90px 40px;">
            <img id="profile-img" class="profile-img-card" src="resources/img/xyymm/fintech_img.png">  

            <h4 style="margin-bottom: 20px;">Evosnap Response Page</h4>

            <div class="container-fluid mer table-responsive" id="wht">

                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/home">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/evosnapTest">Evosnap Test</a></li>
                    <li>Evosnap Response Page</li>
                </ol>

                <div class="body-content" style="padding-left: 15px;">

                    <p>${message}</p>
                    Transaction Details
                    <table style="width: 60%">
                        <tr>
                            <td><s:message code="form.transactionlist.transactionId" /></td>
                            <td>${transaction.transactionId}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><s:message code="form.transactionlist.merchantId" /></td>
                            <td>${transaction.merchantId}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><s:message code="form.transactionlist.customerId" /></td>
                            <td>${transaction.customerId}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><s:message code="form.transactionlist.name" /></td>
                            <td>${transaction.lastName},${transaction.firstName}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><s:message code="form.transactionlist.invoiceNumber" /></td>
                            <td>${transaction.invoiceNum}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><s:message code="form.transactionlist.amount" /></td>
                            <td>${transaction.amount}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><s:message code="form.transactionlist.ipAddress" /></td>
                            <td>${transaction.ipAddress}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><s:message code="form.transactionlist.currency" /></td>
                            <td>${transaction.currency}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><s:message code="form.transactionlist.orderStatus" /></td>
                            <td>${transaction.orderStatus}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /card-container -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <jsp:directive.include file="include_body_scripts.jsp" />
</body>
</html>
```

`

below is my screenshot when I run this jsp file:
[image]

I want background image here which I added as inline css but background image is not dispalayed proper and also logo is not displayed.

Please anybody can help me to get this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe path is wrong, try to change url path. url("../resources/img/xyymm/home.jpg"); or url("./resources/img/xyymm/home.jpg"); according to your path.

Comment: Thanks for your time but I tried this solution but it isn't helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is at
`/FTL/evosnapRedirectController/success/1485323783355`.
The relative URL `resources/img/xyymm/home.jpg` in the inline css resolves to `/FTL/evosnapRedirectController/success/resources/img/xyymm/home.jpg`, but it seems that the resource is actually at `/FTL/resources/img/xyymm/home.jpg`

You need to include the context path in the background URL:

```
background-image      : url("<c:url value='/resources/img/xyymm/home.jpg'/>");
```

or

```
background-image      : url("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/img/xyymm/home.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem just now, and here how I fixed it:

```
.cssProperties {
  background: url("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/../../../assets/images/background.png"); 
}
```

- I kept playing around the pattern as you see here [/../../../], until I matched the right directory path stream.
- I used the MDN Reference, by utilizing VSC IDE intellisense commands "that you can view once you hover on the URL() link that you are creating, and check its destination by Ctrl clicking the link" for a more eye catching, guaranteed results to resolve this problem.